# How do I redirect all non-existent subdomain urls to my main url?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my Drupal site the provided .htaccess file allows me to redirect www.example.com requests to example.com using this code:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

In addition to this, I would also like to point *all* subdomain requests to example.com as well. For example:

- foobar.example.com --> example.com
- wwww.example.com --> example.com
- foo.example.com/mypage.php --> example.com/mypage.php

So, how would I modify the above code to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have another rule after your current rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http%{ENV:protossl}://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^[^.]+\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```